# Convert unlisted matrices within a list back to matrices

Tags: r, lapply

I have two lists of matrices and each list consists of ten 5x5 matrix:

```
List 1:
          [[1]]   
                A           B           C           D           E      
          [1,]  1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000
          [2,]  1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000 
          [3,]  1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000 
          [4,]  1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000 
          [5,]  1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000  
          
          .....
    
          [[10]]   
                 A           B           C           D           E      
          [1,]  7.0000000   3.0000000   5.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000
          [2,]  7.0000000   3.0000000   5.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000 
          [3,]  7.0000000   3.0000000   5.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000 
          [4,]  7.0000000   3.0000000   5.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000 
          [5,]  7.0000000   3.0000000   5.0000000   2.0000000   1.0000000  

List 2:
          [[1]]   
                A           B           C           D           E      
          [1,]  2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000
          [2,]  2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000 
          [3,]  2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000 
          [4,]  2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000 
          [5,]  2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   2.0000000   
          
          .....
    
          [[10]]   
                 A           B           C           D           E      
          [1,]  1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000
          [2,]  1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000 
          [3,]  1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000 
          [4,]  1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000 
          [5,]  1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000
```

I summed the two lists by using lapply (see below) and got the sum result I wanted. However, they are no longer in matrices in my new list.. How do I convert them back so I can export them into CSV as matrices?

lapply code used:

```
lapply(seq_along(List1),function(i)
         unlist(List1[i])+unlist(List2[i])) 

Result:
[[1]]
A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4 E1 E2 E3 E4 
 3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  3  3  3  3
...

[[10]]
A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4 E1 E2 E3 E4 
 8  8  8  8  4  4  4  4  6  6  6  6  3  3  3  3  2  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double bracket so that you are actually adding matrices (instead of a list of 1 matrix that you then convert to a vector with unlist):

```
lapply(seq_along(List1), function(i) List1[[i]] + List2[[i]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `MAP` to sum the matixes of two lists.

```
Map(`+`, List1, List2)
```

Comment: I tried this option too and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Using `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(List1, List2, `+`)
```